# Dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required. Which argument am I missing?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've created item-sending POST-form via context_processors and it works perfectly.
But i want to redirect user to new page ( domain.com/work/{work_id}/ ) after sending form and i have a problem with it.

`dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

**Which argument am I missing in kwargs???**

**app/context_processors.py**

```py
def add_work_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddWorkForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() == False:
            print("Not valid")
        else:
            print("Valid")
            fcc_form = form.save(commit=True)
            
            ### PROBLEM STARTS HERE ###
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={'work_id':fcc_form.id}))

    return {'add_work_form': AddWorkForm(request.POST or None)}
```

**work/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /work/5/
    path('<int:work_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /work/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**work/views.py**

```py
def detail(request, work_id):
    try:
        work = Work.objects.get(pk=work_id)
    except Work.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Work does not exist")
    return render(request, 'work/detail.html', {'work': work})
```

**TRACEBACK**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST

Django Version: 4.1.7
Python Version: 3.10.6
Installed Applications:
['work.apps.WorkConfig',
 'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 486, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 253, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 448, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 408, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 490, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/splitbeast/./work/views.py", line 13, in index
    return render(request, 'work/index.html', context)
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/bobsunday/projects/django_project/venv_django/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 254, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))

Exception Type: ValueError at /work/
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

**Please point to the solution**

Comment: Please post the entire error traceback message.

Comment: A context processor as the name suggests, is only relevant to the context. The only valid return value for a context processor is a dictionary or context object, i.e. you cannot redirect from a context processor. Hmm, and why are you even trying to handle a form in a context processor??

Comment: @JohnGordon 
I added traceback to the question

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i use it because my form must be called from any page. If context processor is wrong way to do this, what should i use?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this via context processor? You can use a Django view to do this instead of a context processor.

Comment: @SanyamKhurana As i understand view, it (with html templates) configurable for each app in project. But my modal form should work everywhere (every page) and my form contains one general html template (app/templates/modal-form.html). How i can call it without context processor and instead of copy in each app view?

Comment: But form still works except redirection...

Comment: Hmmm... i found out something new about using view by classname.  But one question is still actiual for me - should i create def post in each view in project (folders: app, work, poll) ???

Comment: @VladimirSubbotin Thank you for elaborating on what you're trying to do. I've added an answer to this question which would better help you understand the request-response cycle phases in Django and where to handle which information.

Comment: @SanyamKhurana Thank you! This is important information for me, something becomes clearer.

Comment: Glad that it helped. If it resolves your query, you can upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Context Processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#context-processors), as the name suggests, helps in providing extra context to your Django views (which might or might not be rendering a template in that view).

What you're trying to do is to do a response redirect from the context processor **which is not allowed**. A context processor should return a `dict` containing extra context as key-value pair.

The request-response cycle in Django can be broken down into several distinct phases, as follows:

- **The middleware phase**: Is the first phase of the request-response cycle, where the request is processed by a series of middleware components before it reaches the view. Middleware components can perform tasks such as authentication, request/response processing, and caching.
- **The view phase**: This is the second phase of the request-response cycle, where the view function or class-based view is called to generate the response. The view can interact with the database, perform calculations, and prepare the data for rendering.
- **The rendering phase**: This is the third phase of the request-response cycle, where the response content is generated by rendering a template or using a content-type-specific renderer.
- **The response phase**: This is the final phase of the request-response cycle, where the response is returned to the client.

Context processors run during the rendering phase of the request-response cycle after the view has prepared the data for rendering but before the response is generated. During this phase, Django collects the context data from various sources, including the view and any context processors that are defined in the TEMPLATES settings. The collected context data is then passed to the template engine to generate the response content.

Now, if you want to have this form displayed on all the pages of your website and want to process it, you can create a template (`my-form.html`) with just the form like:

```
<div id="my-awesome-form">
    <!-- Add your form here -->
</div>
```

Now you can include this form in every HTML page using `{% include %}` as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% include "my-form.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

This avoids any replication of HTML code. Now, in your view, you can handle it.

Another thing, that one might think of is to handle this in middleware, instead of views. Please remember, it is technically possible albeit not recommended. Middleware is specifically for cross-cutting concerns such as caching, request/response processing, auth, etc., and not for business logic like this.